# Running Xamarin code as root on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, root

I am developing an app with Xamarin.Android. I want to process files in the /system partition of a device, so I need root access. Is there any way I can run C# or C++ code as root, given that the target device is rooted with SU present?

EDIT: I successfully compiled C/++ code for ARM and I executed it using a root shell. This gave it full SU access. The question about running C# code as root still remains though.

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to configure SU to give your app root permissions?

Comment: @bodangly This lets me run SU commands but not C# code as SU, or at least I couldn't make it do that.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21437/app-with-root-access) might help you. It helped me.

Comment: This article is about running commands as root, while I wanted to run C# or C++ code as stated above.